Issue with downloading and replacing files, and other problems when running the executable generated by PyInstaller
I'm facing an issue when trying to download and replace files in a Python application using PyInstaller. My application consists of downloading files from the internet and replacing existing ones locally. (Update my game files).
The code works perfectly fine when I run the Python script directly (.py), but when I generate an executable using PyInstaller (pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=icone.ico PWULauncher.py), the downloaded files are saved with a temporary format with 0 bytes (e.g., .1ad61sadtemp) and are not replaced correctly.
Additionally, the function responsible for starting the game also does not work when running the executable, same problem.
I've tried several solutions, such as running the executable as an administrator, setting folder permissions, and using different flags in PyInstaller, but the issue persists.
Here's the code snippet responsible for downloading and replacing files:
# Code snippet responsible for downloading and replacing files
def DownloadFile(self, url, destination):
    try:
        gdown.download(url, destination, quiet=False)
        print("File downloaded successfully:", destination)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error downloading the file:", e)

# Calling the function to download a file
self.DownloadFile("FILE_URL", "LOCAL_DESTINATION")

Here's the code for start my game:
# Code snippet responsible for starting the game
def start_game(self, game_exe_path, username, password, character_name, idx):
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  # Get the script directory
    current_dir = os.getcwd()  # Store the current directory
    os.chdir(script_dir)  # Change to the script directory
    game_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, "game")  # Define the game directory
    os.chdir(game_dir)  # Change to the game directory
    try:
        if os.path.exists(game_exe_path):
            subprocess.Popen([game_exe_path, 'startbypatcher', f'user:{username}', f'pwd:{password}', f'role:{character_name}'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
            # Add the new game window to the list
            self.game_windows.append(game_exe_path)
            # Add hotkey for the new window
            hotkey = f'ctrl+shift+{idx}'
            self.hotkeys.append(hotkey)
            try:
                keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, lambda idx=len(self.game_windows) - 1: self.focus_window(idx))
                print(f"Hotkey '{hotkey}' added successfully for the window {len(self.game_windows)}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error adding hotkey '{hotkey}':", e)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "The game executable was not found.")
    finally:
        os.chdir(script_dir)  # Restore the original directory

Does anyone have any insights or suggestions on what might be causing these issues when running the application as an executable? (also occurs as .pyw)
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
And if it helps, my imports:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import os
import threading
import gdown
import json
import subprocess
import time
import pygetwindow as gw
import keyboard
import win32gui
import win32con

I'm facing an issue in a Python application using PyInstaller, the code works perfectly fine when I run the Python script directly (.py).
I've tried several solutions, such as running the executable as an administrator, setting folder permissions, and using different flags in PyInstaller, but the issue persists.

After conducting further tests, I managed to resolve the issue with the button to start the game. However, the update function still remains problematic.
I found that it only works if I generate the .exe with the console enabled, without "--noconsole":
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icone.ico PWULauncher.py

Unfortunately this is only a partial answer as I would prefer to be able to disable the console completely and not cause issues with this update function.
